# Using <random> in C++

Tags: c++, random

Thanks in advance for reading.  I am completely new to C++ (though not programming in general) and don't really understand much.  The problems I am working on requires a large quantity of high-quality random numbers, and the default rand() function isn't sufficient.  I tried using the "random" library but couldn't get it to work.  The following simple code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mt19937 gen(random_device());
    normal_distribution<double> randn(0.0, 1.0);
    double t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        t = randn(gen); //program compiles correctly if call to randn is omitted
        cout << t << "\n";
    }
    int a;
    cin >> a;

}
```

Fails to compile, giving me 10 errors, most along the lines of:

```
error C2780: '_Rty std::_Nrand(_Engine &,float,_Rty)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
```

I tried other generators and probability distributions - same problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

```
mt19937 gen(random_device());
```

This is an example of the so-called *most vexing parse*. The compiler actually parses this as a declaration of a *function* called `gen` which takes an argument of type `random_device()` (i.e., function taking zero arguments and returning `std::random_device`) and returning `std::mt19937`. So first you would have to change it to:

```
mt19937 gen(random_device{}); // new C++11 uniform initialization syntax
```

But this is still wrong, because the argument to the constructor of `std::mt19937` is supposed to be a seed value. `random_device{}` is an object which *produces* a seed value when you invoke its `operator()`. So the *actual* correct declaration is:

```
mt19937 gen(random_device{}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the generator incorrectly. You should be creating a `std::random_device` object and then calling it like a function and passing the result to the `std::mt19937` constructor:

```
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
```

Your current code is demonstrating what is known as the "most vexing parse" in C++. Specifically, the following is a function declaration:

```
mt19937 gen(random_device());
```

It declares a function called `gen` that returns a `mt19937` and takes a single argument which is a function returning `random_device` and taking no arguments. If you had corrected this to be a variable definition, you would have received an error saying that you were passing the wrong type argument to the `mt19937` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
mt19937 gen(random_device());
```

has two problems.

Firstly, this is the so-called "most vexing parse", and is interpreted as a function declaration (a function called `gen` which takes a pointer to a function returning `random_device` as its parameter).

Secondly, `random_device` is a type, so `random_device()` is an object of that type. To get a random number out of that, you want `random_device()()`.

The following should fix both problems:

```
random_device dev;
mt19937 gen(dev());
```

or, if you want the device to be temporary,

```
auto seed = random_device()();
mt19937 gen(seed);
```